# How do I use Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, markdown, private-messaging

I asked my first question here a few minutes ago and Pascal Martin was kind enough to improve its formatting. I have two questions:

1. Is there a FAQ that explains how to use text formatting for questions?
2. Is there some way to send a private message to a forum member (like there is in vBulletin-based forums)?

Comment: StackOverflow is NOT a forum. And see /faq for the faq...

Comment: [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: When you typed in your question have you seen this huge yellow box on the right of the editor? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @BrunoLM why is this not a forum? What is a definition of the forum? I think when several people discussing issues, it's pretty much makes it a forum. If this is not a forum, then what is this?

Comment: @Dmitri: It's a question and answer site. But you knew that.

Comment: I knew that, but I think it's like a subset of a forum, forum is a superclass, q&a is instanceof Forum

Comment: @Dmitri If forum was a superclass (or base class), then q&a would be a descendant, heir, child class or subclass, not an instance.

Answer (score 12):

1. The big orange question mark at the top-right of the editor gives you formatting help.
2. No.